# How to pack my Python 3 program so I can release it

Tags: python, python-3.x, packing

I'm using Pygame. How and which files should I consider including with the script so everyone can run it? I'm using python 3.2 therefore py2exe doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**cx_Freeze**](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)! It really works. And its author does not ignore the existence of Python 3. In fact, the version for Python 3.3 is already out, after only a few days that it has been released.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It works great. It's also really easy to use it. (I just had external version of python which was making cx confused about its location) Now everything is ok!